# Upgrade from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.2 on Windows resulted in 5 second page loads

Tags: php, mysql, windows

Apache/2.4.34 (Win32) on Windows 10.

I had PHP 5.6 running fine with instant page loads.

After I upgraded to PHP 7.2.12 any page will now take up to 5 seconds to load.
Even `<?php echo "test" ?>` takes 5 seconds.

Anyone have a suggestion where to start look?

Comment: I don't think this issue has anything to do with PHP, maybe there's something else with your machine. Try to reinstall the whole stack and see if it'll work.

Comment: I did not touch Apache or anything else, I just replaced the PHP directory with the newer version. I did however try to upgrade Apache to latest version (2.4.37), but it didn't help.

Comment: It depends on your settings, I mean there's no answer for this vague question, you have to be more specific, like how did you install Apache & PHP? Are you using LAMP stack like the wamp server? xampp? or what? If the issue persists, then just try to reinstall the whole stack and try again.